# laravel sql subquery

Tags: sql, laravel

I have read the docs about raw queries but they say nothing about building subqueries. Can't I just enter raw sql inside a controller action or model at worst?)

i have two tables, rates and performance.

I cant get to write in Laravel parlance (either query builder or eloquent or raw query) in the controller (or model) the following sql subquery

```
SELECT ratedescription 
FROM rates
WHERE rates.digit
IN (SELECT
   performance.score
   FROM performances
   where performances.id = $i);
```

the $i is a parameter that goes into the method in the controller

This question is NOT for bouty. I have never said that, and it is SO who does it without even asking me.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't use Laravel in a long time but can't you manage to do the same this with query builder?
[laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses)

Something like :

```
Rate::select("ratedescription")->whereIn("digit", function($query) {
    $query->from("performances")->select("score")->where(...);
})->get();
```

My answermight be wrong since I'm didn't use either laravel or php for some time now but I hope it can help.
Have a nice day.

Comment: IT DOESN'T WORK LIKE THIS HERE!